# Is it good approach to write Kafka Streams for persisting into database?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

Just wondering what sort of problems I might face while writing persistence layer with Kafka Streams Builder, or any suggestions to use like Kafka Connect JDBC (Sink)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [Kafka Connect](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues)—streaming from a topic to a datastore is precisely what it is for :)

If you want to process/enrich your data before landing it to a database you can use KStreams (or KSQL), and stream to a second topic, which you then hook up to Connect.